# 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int' in case if function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have trouble running the following query.

I need to find a number of [ID]s used per each model per each day of week. I don't have trouble running similar query to sum up other metrics.

But in this case I receive a message "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '07:2767:90:56' to data type int".

I can execute a count query for [ID] without (case if) function with no trouble.

```
SELECT model,

 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =2 THEN (ID)else 0 END) AS [Monday]
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =3 THEN (ID)else 0 END) AS [Tuesday]
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =4 THEN (ID)else 0 END) AS [Wednesday]
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =5 THEN (ID)else 0 END) AS [Thursday]
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =6 THEN (ID)else 0 END) AS [Friday]

from clientdata 

where [date] between cast ((GETDATE() -7) AS date) and cast (GETDATE()-1 AS date)
group by d.model;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT model,

 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,[date])=2 THEN ID else 0 END) AS [Monday],
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,[date])=3 THEN ID else 0 END) AS [Tuesday],
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,[date])=4 THEN ID else 0 END) AS [Wednesday],
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,[date])=5 THEN ID else 0 END) AS [Thursday],
 count(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday,[date])=6 THEN ID else 0 END) AS [Friday]

from clientdata  d

where [date] between (GETDATE() -7) and (GETDATE()-1)
group by d.model;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are getting that specific error, but I see several problems:

- No commas after fields in your select (need one after Monday, Tuesday, etc.)
- You are grouping by d.model where d is not a valid table alias
- Your query will not return the results you are looking for.  All the counts will be the same for the days.  You want to use SUM, something along the lines of:

  SUM(CASE WHEN datepart(weekday, [date]) =2 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS [Monday]